# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Not able to click on any button in the application.

Error stack trace:

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.10.0', revision: '176b4a9', time: '2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z'
System info: host: 'SHIPAWAR-54Q9D', ip: '10.65.75.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

I tried java script executor, actions class but none of them worked

```
 public void clickHERE(String deal) throws Throwable{   
    javaScriptClick(driver, HERE);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(enterDeal)).sendKeys(deal);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    int ok_size=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("[name=SearchDeal]")).size();
    System.out.println("the search button size:" +ok_size);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath(enterDeal)).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    scrollToElement(driver, nextTabDealInfo);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(nextTabDealInfo)).click(); // this button in not working

}
```

should be able to click the button.

`nextTabDealInfo` is the xpath:

```
//*[@type='button' and contains(@value,'Next Tab')]
```

HTML for button:

```
<input type="button" name="fromOptyInfoTab" value="Next Tab >" onclick="return switchTabs('nonStandardInfo.do');" class="buttonNextTab">
```

Comment: can you share the HTML page you are working on?

Comment: What's `nextTabDealInfo`?

Comment: nextTabDealInfo is the xpath. xpath : //*[@type='button' and contains(@value,'Next Tab')]

Comment: please find below html for button:<input type="button" name="fromOptyInfoTab" value="Next Tab >" onclick="return switchTabs('nonStandardInfo.do');" class="buttonNextTab">

Comment: @shivampawar : is it visible in UI when selenium try to click on it ? or do you have to scroll down/up to see the element interaction ?

Comment: @cruisepandey I have to scroll down. actually this thing is working in firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
.
System info: host: 'SHIPAWAR-54Q9D', ip: '10.65.75.122', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_60'
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to communicate with the **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.10.0* of *2018-03-02T19:03:16.397Z* which is almost an year older.
- Your *JDK version* is **1.8.0_60** which is pretty old and ancient.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *JDK v8u60* , *Selenium Client v3.10.0*

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u202**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: this has nothing to do with JDK version.. it's simply a mismatch of chromedriver and selenium

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=73.0.3683.103)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
System info: host: 'SHIPAWAR-54Q9D', ip: '10.75.234.66', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver - still getting this error on updating the JDK

Comment: The HTML of the element in the current form `<input type="button" name="fromOptyInfoTab" value="Next Tab >" onclick="return switchTabs('nonStandardInfo.do');" class="buttonNextTab">` looks invalid. Can you cross check one?